# cmake does not include sub directory when building

Tags: cmake

I am using cmake to build my c++ project.

I have my CmakeList.txt and my main.cpp in the src folder.

Main includes LogStream.h in src\log. When I run cmake and then make I get the error....

```
fatal error: LogStream.h: No such file or directory
 #include "LogStream.h"
```

I have looked for a while to find a tutorial to include a sub folder in cmake. I for some reason can not find a simple straight forward tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `include_directories`, example: `include_directories(src/log)`