# How to configure include directories so a logical module's source file can include its associated header with a path prefixed with the module name?

Tags: cmake

I put my c++ classes header and associated source file together in the same directory. My directories are organized by modules.

How do I configure CMake such that `module1/myclass.cpp` can include its associated header file like "`#include <module1/myclass.h>`"?

Note: I am using CMake on windows to produce MinGW Makefiles.

Comment: If you #include the header file, it will be dependant; you don't need to do anything special in your CMakeLists.  Having the header file in the same directory as the cpp as you want will make sure it's found, so you don't need to mess with header search paths.

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578594/cmake-does-not-include-sub-directory-when-building/33578725#33578725 ?

Comment: @fghj I've edited to clarify this question. I don't think it's a duplicate of the dup target you've suggested.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like my cmake configuration to have any cpp be dependent on its corresponding h file.

CMake will automatically work out the dependencies among your cpp and h files. It does this by using your platform build tools. For example, it knows how to tell gcc to generate dependency files, and then it can process that file. On other platforms like with Visual Studio, CMake knows how to tell cl.exe to output header dependencies and it can parse that output too.

You don't need to do anything special to get CMake to correctly handle your header dependencies. All you have to do is make sure the headers are found during compilation.

> If I have src/module1/myclass.cpp listed in my add_executable line, where will cmake look for myclass.h if myclass.cpp lists #include ?

The compiler will look in its default locations, and you can configure additional search paths by running the `include_directories(...)` command (to set them for the whole CMakeLists.txt file) or by running `target_include_directories(your_executable_target ...)` to set them for just the one executable.

If your header files are all stored alongside the cpp files, and you give `#include` relative paths from the cpp file location (and you use `#include "..."` instead of `#include <...>`) then you don't need to configure header search paths: all compilers that I'm aware of search relative to the cpp file by default.

Answer (score -1):

Use `target_include_directories` and specify the name of the directory which contains your module's directory.

Note that if that parent directory also contains other modules, this could have an undersireable effect of allowing source files in module1 to resolve include paths for headers from modules that module1 is not intended to know about. To solve that, you can add an additional intermediate directory also with the name of the module name (Ex. ".../module1/module1/"), where the outer one achieves the logical separation between different modules, and is the one that you specify in the `target_include_directories` command, and the inner one is the one that allows you to continue to include header files in a way that "namespaces" the headers belonging to a module by their module name. It's not pretty, but I think that's just how it is with so many compilers (or is it "compiler drivers?") adopting what is the conventional behaviour of specifying include directories.