# CMake get all referenced header files

Tags: c++, cmake

I have configured cmake to scan the my `include/` folder for *.cpp and *.h files. This folder contains all the sources and header the actual program needs. Also cmake scans `test/` for files called `testXX.cpp`. These files each contain a main method and test parts of the implementations in `include/`. Then CMake automatically generates targets for every `testXX.cpp` file it finds and links everything together,so I end up with multiple executables called `testXX`

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC
    "include/*.cpp"
    #"libs/*.c"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER
    "include/*.h"
    #"libs/*.h"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TEST
    "test/*.h"
    "test/*.cpp"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE EXTRA_LIBS
    "lib/*.a"
)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -Wall  -fopenmp -O3 -funroll-loops  -march=native -mtune=native -ftree-vectorize" )

#message(${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})

foreach( testsourcefile ${TEST} )
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(testname ${testsourcefile} NAME)
    string( REPLACE ".cpp" "" testname ${testname} )

    #message(${HEADER})
    #message(${testname})
    #message(${EXTRA_LIBS})

    add_executable( ${testname} ${testsourcefile} ${HEADER} ${SRC}) 
    target_link_libraries( ${testname} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${EXTRA_LIBS})

endforeach( testsourcefile ${TEST} )
```

So far this works perfectly, with a minor problem. Every executable gets all header and source files - regardless if they are needed or not. So every header/source file is compiled, for every `testXX.cpp` even if this file doesnt use most of the header/source files. Maybe there is a way to dynamically set `${HEADER}` and `${SRC}` to only contain the needed headers/sources?

gcc/g++ has an option `MMD` to find all referenced header/sources - maybe this can be used here? Any ideas?

Comment: The first comment would be this: globbing the sources and headers is explicitly discouraged by the CMake developers (and also the developers of other tools).  It can lead to all sorts of problems, so I would suggest you reconsider whether the cost/benefit is worth it.

The second comment would be that if you are using the same source files for all the executables, it would be worth building a static library and then linking that library into each executable.  Any unused object files will be dropped at link time.  The executables then need no dependencies on the library headers or sources.

Comment: CMake already uses header files' discovering and automatically recompile sources after headers have been changed. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33598834/3440745).

Comment: @tsyvarev Not true in my case. I have a source file only depending on `Helper.h` and nothing else. However, `objdump -d | less` shows me, that there are some functions in the binary file from other header files - e.g. some mean calculations, which are nowhere referenced in the code!
@RogerLeigh Any other ideas how to not manually edit CMakeList in case I add a new `testXX.cpp` file?

Comment: `that there are some functions in the binary file from other header files` - So, if you will edit some of this header file, futher `make` will *automatically* recompile source. This is what you want, isn't it? `Any other ideas how to not manually edit CMakeList in case I add a new testXX.cpp file?` - `CMakeLists.txt` is **intended** to be manually edited when you add new source. So, when you build with `make`, whole reconfiguration process (`cmake`) will be performed automatically. With your current implementation you need to *explicitely* run `cmake` after adding the source.

Comment: No! If I have `program1.cpp` depending only on `header1.h`, why would I need to recompile it when I change `header2.h`? At the moment that happens because of my CMakeList configuration. I dont mind running `cmake` by hand every time I add a new file - Since I know when that happens, there is no real need for automagic here. But I dont want to add another 20 lines of source/header definitions to my CMakeList.txt everytime I add a new `testXX.cpp` file / executable - for that I am to lazy